# How to position an element at the bottom of a page in JSX?

Tags: javascript

I wanted to know how I could achieve this in JSX. I've tried using CSS styling as follows but I want to fix the bottom position while simultaneously inheriting the left from the parent. If I don't inherit left the container doesn't fall in line with my other components.

```
<div className="container" style={{ position: "fixed", bottom: "10%", left: "want to inherit from parent element here" }}>
```

Would appreciate any help!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// parent element
<div 
  style={{
    position: 'relative',
    backgroundColor: 'orange',
    height: '100vh',
    width: '100vw',
    marginLeft: 100,
  }}
>
  // child element
  <div 
    style={{
      position: 'fixed',
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
      height: '10vh',
      width: '10vw',
      bottom: 0,
      left: 'inherit'
    }}
  >
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi this didn't really work for me. My whole code is here if that might be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <Router>
    <div
      className="container-fluid"
      style={{
        height: "100vh",
        width: "100%",
        backgroundImage: `url(${world_map})`,
        backgroundSize: "auto",
      }}
    >
      <NavBar />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={MainMenu} />
        <Route path="/services" component={ServicesMenu} />
        <Route path="/autoconnect" component={AutoConnectMenu} />
        <Route path="/gatt" component={GATTMenu} />
        <Route path="/characteristics" component={CharMenu} />
        <Route path="/scan" component={ScanMenu} />
        <Route path="/connect" component={ConnMenu} />
        <Route path="/write" component={WriteMenu} />
        <Route path="/notify" component={NotifyMenu} />
      </Switch>
      <div
        className="container"
        style={{ position: "fixed", bottom: "10px", left: "inherit" }}
      >
        <div className={"alert alert-" + this.state.msgType}>
          <span
            style={{
              fontFamily: "helvetica",
              fontWeight: "bold",
            }}
          >
            Message from Base Station:
          </span>
          {this.state.msg}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </Router>
```